# Using Custom UI Graphics in Storyboards?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, storyboard

I feel this is a simple question with a simple answer, but while using a storyboard, can I still use custom images for UIButtons in the same way you do when creating your viewcontrollers programmatically? I would like to create my project flow using storyboard and then go back to tweak the UI to my liking once the views are all connected and content is filled in. Is this possible?

Thank you for your help!
-Taz88

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when you have a question, it's faster to just try it out in Xcode instead of asking on stackoverflow.

Anyway, yes.  You can create custom `UIButton`s in a storyboard with your own images.

Comment: Yeah this should be the accepted answer because of the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Click on the UIButton on the storyboard and set it to a custom type, then give it an image the same way as you would in a normal .xib file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what the others have said, you can do *everything* with regard to views, using a storyboard, that you can do generating view controllers and their views in other ways. You do not have to generate a view controller's view from within the storyboard; you can make it in code, or get it from a nib, just as you might do if you were obtaining the view controller in some other way.